# how to change a variable in the body of the loop?

Tags: python-3.x

Sample Input 1:

- 10 - starting value
- 50 - percentage increase in the population
- 6 - number of repetitions

Sample Output 1:

```
1 10.0
2 15.0
3 22.5
4 33.75
5 50.625
6 75.9375
```

what code have I done at the moment

```py
m, p, n = float(input('')),float(input('')),int(input(''))
for i in range(n):
    # m - стартовое количество популяции
    # n - количество повторений
    # p - среднесуточное увелечение(от предыдущего расписать формулу)
    r = m * ((p / 100))
    m = m + (r * i)
    print(m)
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you multiply `m` by a factor proportional to the iteration, but `m` has already been multiplied before. Fix your code as:

```py
m, p, n = float(input('')),float(input('')),int(input(''))
for i in range(n):
    # m - стартовое количество популяции
    # n - количество повторений
    # p - среднесуточное увелечение(от предыдущего расписать формулу)
    print(m)
    r = m * ((p / 100))
    m = m + r
```

Alternatively, do the calculation inside the loop, without storing the value in m:

```py
m, p, n = float(input('')),float(input('')),int(input(''))
r = p / 100
for i in range(n):
    print(m*(1+r)**i)
```